# Create database on Azure using Entiitty Framework

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, azure

I want to create ASP.NET MVC app using database on Azure. I have already written model classes for database. But how can attach this database or tables on azure?? It's connections string for my already created DB, which i want to use.

```
<add name="AccomodationContext" connectionString="Server=tcp:student-docs.database.windows.net,1433;Database=docDb;User ID={username};Password={password};Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

It's empty, I would like to use it to has a tables created from my model classes, or create a new database. But I can't find, how should look correct connection string. I know that for LocalDB there is 'AttachDbFilename' in connection string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have a connection called `DefaultConnection` in your web.config that you can place your connections string in.

You can get the actual connection string directly from your Azure portal.

[image: Azure SQL Database Properties]

[image: Connection Strings]